# Is the Maldekian crop circle a hoax?

Tags: aliens, crop-circles

This is known as the Maldekian crop circle

[image: Maldekian crop circle]

which (according to [this link](http://yowusa.com/et/2003/et-2003-05a/3.shtml)) contains a message:

> Beware the bearers of FALSE gifts & their BROKEN PROMISES.Much PAIN But Still time.(unclear word).There is GOOD out there.We oppose DECEPTION.COnduit CLOSING\

According to the RedGrittyBrick's comment, *It seems to be a genuine 2002 cornfield art-work by anonymous fun-loving Hampshire artists.* Can any human technology available to common people create this (probably) overnight during reduced visibility? How?

[Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crop_circle) that these images usually appear overnight (it seems this is the case since there is no evidence about its creation; during the day somebody would probably notice). Some similar crop circles are beautiful and seemingly difficult to create [like this](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/650/are-crop-circles-man-made), but they mostly consist of simple circles ind lines, maybe even some GPS tracking points. Here the width of the lines requires great deal of precision, so the difference from other crop circles is the complexity: note well shaped spiral on the disc, the end of its track and the exact width of the lines on the face.

Comment: afaik no crop circle has ever been proven not to have been either a hoax or perfectly natural (twisters, etc.). Your implied claim that this specific one is supernatural, divine, or whatever other than man made or a weather phenomenon is what needs proving, not the reverse.

Comment: Please explain what the claim is that is being made in the video so not everyone has to watch the whole thing. It isn't clear what the text you are citing refers to without watching the video.

Comment: OK, I did explain the question a little bit. From what I've googled, I just wonder why this is not investigated by anyone but dreamers. It seems to be hoax, but I can't find any good link about it.

Comment: It probably isn’t investigated because there’s no reason to suspect that it’s anything but a hoax. Investigating it would be a waste of time – see [Russell’s teapot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell%27s_teapot). The notable claim here is “this is *not* a hoax”, not the other way round.

Comment: What do you mean "hoax", It seems to be a *genuine* 2002 cornfield art-work by anonymous fun-loving Hampshire artists. Has anyone provided any solid evidence for an alternative explanation?

Comment: I've updated the question again, hope it is better now. I'f not, please point out, thanks for guiding me how to build a correct question - this alone is quite useful.

Comment: Don't know if it's better, because I didn't see it earlier, but it's still not good. // It is good that you provide a couple links, but note what Oddthinking said about video. // Your reference to Russel's Teapot is awkward and unexplained. // It is not clear what your question is. // Even if you clarify the question, there is likely a problem. If you are asking about its *existence*, Sancho and RedGritty have the answer. If you're asking what some of us assume you're asking, this is very old material, and you need to explain why this should be any different from the many other crop circles.

Comment: @hunter2 Updated again. RedGrittyBrick's comment doesn't assume ET intelligence to explain this, so it should be investigated first. It would explain this if such a crop can be created by group of artist over night.

Comment: Careful about 'first'; this isn't a normal forum, if you want to ask another question, you need to post a fresh question // But OK - The claim is that this thing *exists*, you're skeptical that it could be created, and you are asking how people can make crop circles/icons/images - right? If so, that's a coherent question.  That said, this is likely a duplicate. I'm not the expert, and standards vary between different SE sites, but I think "How are crop circles made?" is very covered ground, if you want to search (this site or elsewhere).

Comment: Where does the 'overnight' part come from?   Have you looked at other 'crop-art' explanations?  (If so, you could link a couple and explain why they don't apply.) // (So, at the very least, what's wrong with this?) http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/650/are-crop-circles-man-made // Also, in my last comment, I guess that should be "skeptical this could be created by people" (and you've now upped it to "overnight")

Comment: "A great deal of precision". Humans can arrange ink on paper to a precision of 1/600 in. Why wouldn't humans be able to mark accurate lines in a cornfield?

Comment: "Usually" is not specfic to this case. Who said that this one appeared overnight? / Why do you think someone would notice a half-made piece in the daytime? Ever look at a field of tall crops (like a corn maze) from the side? Your suggestion that this piece requires greater precision than the triskelion from the links seems baseless. Are you familiar with the technology and precision involved in modern farm equipment? // You've made this a 'moving target'. Please stop changing your question, and think about what you're asking. How is this not a duplicate of the question that is now linked?

Comment: Sorry if my tone is getting less friendly. Agreed this is not a chat. I'm signing off for the weekend in a minute. My answer would be to flag this as a duplicate.  I could've left out the part you indicate, but otherwise, I think these are still notable problems with your question. // (I'll meet you half way - I deleted the snarkier comment. The other problems remain, as I see it.)

Comment: @JanTuroň - They're usually created by frequencies (cymatics). But this seems to be different.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> **Can any human technology available to common people create this (probably) over night during reduced visibility? How?**

### Maldekian

A better name for this artwork is the "Crabwood Formation" as it is a corn-drawing revealed on August 15, 2002 at Crabwood near Winchester in Hampshire, England.

### Human technology

To flatten crops in circles, you just need stone-age technology such as ropes and planks. [Ref](http://www.guardian.co.uk/uk/2009/jun/05/ruralaffairs)

To make complex designs you can make use of a few additional items such as laser pointers, night vision goggles etc. [Ref](http://www.wikihow.com/Make-a-Crop-Circle)

### Common People

Common people can do this but you should note that commercial enterprises do this too, they can afford better tools. [Ref](http://circlemakers.org/totc2007.html) They have made examples of complex [spiral forms](http://www.circlemakers.org/natgeo.html).

### Over night

To some extent, adding more people makes the job faster. Careful planning and practice must also be helpful.

The reason some designs are not adjacent to roads (and therefore have to be signalled to the press by an anonymous phone call) are so that they can be constructed over several days (and/or nights)

Some of the alleged witnesses of the Crabwood formation state that it was created over several nights [Ref](http://www.lucypringle.co.uk/articles/crabwood/)

Comment: Excellent investigative answer. Did you find the links by simple googling?

Comment: @Jan: Yes. When a subject catches my interest and I have time, I enjoy using Google to find information and misinformation - and trying to sift one from the other. I have a lot of books, but not on this sort of subject.

Comment: +1 For the reference to commercial crop circle makers. There's no reason that these necessarily appear in secret, overnight, without the owner of the property knowing. It's entirely possible that the owner of a farm might pay somebody to come make artwork in their field, for a bit of publicity.